# React-Native: error while installing module for Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to react native and tried to install the navigation module by following commands in MAC:

1. `npm install @react-navigation/native`
2. `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`.

from the document link of https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started but was unlucky struck with an error which i tried lot to clear,The error is in below link:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBy0P.jpg)

Kindly request you to clear this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal run the following command: cd ios && pod install && cd..